# How to insert Equations(mathematical) generated from Excel into mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, excel, equations

I have a set of equations generated using Microsoft Excel which needs to be inserted into MySQL database. Is there a way to do it ?

For Example :

I wanted to insert the following equation into MySQL database.

[image]

This was generated using Microsoft Excel using the Equations option available under Insert menu.

I was able to insert and retrieve symbols like (ψ,€, etc.,) using utf-8 Unicode collation.Also I am aware that the equations could be converted into an image and saved as blob objects. But is there a way I could directly insert and retrieve equations using MySQL database.

.